# Wso2 with jrockit JVM

Tags: wso2

We are looking to run WSO2 with JRockit 1.6 JVM, are there any known issues or we need to use Hotspot JVM?

I could not find documentation if JRockit is supported, but wanted to check as we use JRockit in our Production for high performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 products only support Oracle and IBM JVMs. See http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Installation+Prerequisites

This means that we cannot guarantee that WSO2 products will support JRockit. However you are welcome to try it out.

I hope you have a pre-production environment to test this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i see a comment "Oracle and IBM JRE 1.7 are also supported when running (not building) WSO2 products." assuming that means Oracle Jrockit??